# Clone children and text of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Best all I got the following situation, I need to clone the contents of an element with all the events attached to it, this works only I can't clone the text with it, like shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EaterOfCode/QPMjH/1/):

HTML:

```
<div class="source">Say bye bye, little text!
    <span class="stay">I'm gonna clone!</span>
More text
</div>

<div class="destination">

</div>

<button>Clone!</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.source').children().clone(true,true).appendTo($('.destination'));
});
```

How do I get that working? that the text also get cloned without cloning the parent container in the destination or changing the html input?

Comment: Don't you simply copy the content of `source` in `destination`? `$('.destination').html($('.source').html());` i guess can help you.

Comment: @Ragnarokkr with that I'll lose all my events

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I didn't see you need to keep the events. Sorry.

Comment: @Ragnarokkr it's okay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `.source` is parent class then try this .

```
$('.destination').append(
    $('.source').clone( true )
).find('.source').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: does this still respect events?

Comment: isn't this a more safe way of doing that http://jsfiddle.net/EaterOfCorpses/QPMjH/5/ but anyways thanks :) exactly what I was looking for :) without any wrapper

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.source').clone(true,true).appendTo($('.destination'));
```

You're currently cloning just a children node which is `<span>`

upd: or you can append html of an object to another object:

```
$('.destination').append($('.source').html());
```

**upd2**: since what you clone is a user input, and you have some kind of string containg whole input you append it to .source as:

```
$(".source").append('<span id="some_id">' + user_input + '</span>');
```

And clone it:

```
$(".source").find("#some_id").clone(true,true).appendTo($('.destination'));
```

Comment: but I don't want to add the parent container to be added to destination :(

Comment: but that will lose all the events :(

Comment: Totally don't get your idea :). Just wrap whatever you are going to clone to another tag such as `<span>` or '<div>`

Comment: the problem is that I can't, the HTML is user input and I need to put a wrapper around it without cloning the parent container because that is a TR in my original code

Comment: user input comes from PHP and is everything between `<table>` and `</table>` it's from my plugin for Smarty, thanks for the help anyway see kasyx answer :)

Comment: i don't see any fundamental difference there, solution is same

Comment: with his answer I don't lose the event's with yours I do, so yes basically the answer is the same except from that

Comment: The answer was: wrap whatever you are going to clone to another tag such as `<span>` or `div`, nothing else :)

Answer (score 1):

Youre cloning only children now. I suggest you to wrap content with span. Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QPMjH/3/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $clonedSource = $('.source').clone(true);
    $clonedSource.wrapInner('<span>');
    $clonedSource.children().clone(true,true).appendTo($('.destination'));
});
```

or just in one line:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.source').clone(true).wrapInner('<span>').children().clone(true,true).appendTo($('.destination'));
});
```

Comment: but I don't want to add the parent container be added to destination

Comment: You can wrap then content with another `<span>` or `<div>`. Is it acceptable?

Comment: I can't control the user input, so I can't wrap it in a `<span>` via the html it needs to be done via javascript

Comment: Thanks! that's what I searched for :)